# Updating variables in multi variables gradient descent

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

In gradient descent of a function F($\theta_1$,$\theta_2$), in the update step after doing $\theta_1' \leftarrow \theta_1 - \alpha \frac{\sigma F}{\sigma\theta_1}$ when we update $\theta_2$, do we use the old value of $\theta_1$ or we use the updated one $\theta_1'$?

**Edit**: Do we  use the same $\alpha$ step size for both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Comment: @Sally thank you. just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often you will see the update written will all $\theta$s together as 
$$
\pmb{\theta}' \gets \pmb{\theta}-\mathbf{\alpha}\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \pmb{\theta}}
$$
indicating that both happen simultaneously (use the old value) and use the same value $\alpha$.